# Check if turtles are in other turtles' radius

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that checks whether a turtle will be inside the radius of any other turtles. I have done this by using two for loops that loop through the whole array. This seems to slow down after i add a lot of turtles to the array. Is there a way to make it more efficient?

```
public void inRadius() {
        for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++) {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < turtles.size(); k++) {
               CartesianCoordinate position = new CartesianCoordinate(turtles.get(i).getXPosition(), turtles.get(i).getYPosition());
                turtles.get(k).checkRadius(position);
                if(turtles.get(k).checkRadius(position)) {
                System.out.println(turtles.get(k)+":"+turtles.get(k).checkRadius(position));
                
                    }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the check radius method:

```
    public boolean checkRadius(CartesianCoordinate point) {
    
        double distance = Math.pow(point.getX()-getXPosition(),2) + Math.pow(point.getY()-getYPosition(),2);
        
        double rad =Math.pow(radius, 2);
        
        if (distance < rad) {
            inRadius=true;
        }
        if(distance> rad) {
            inRadius= false;
        }
        return inRadius;
        
    }
```

Comment: How does it help you to know that turtles are in each other's radius? Wouldn't you want to know before they move whether they would end up in each other's radius? Perhaps you are calling this inRadius method too often?

Comment: I am trying to implement flocking behaviour, so they start moving in random directions and when their radius gets entered by another turtle, certain flocking behaviors will occur. Separation, alignment, cohesion etc.

Comment: You're right i was calling inRadius too often, it was nested in another loop of the same array, many thanks.

Comment: Also, you can replace `pow(x, 2)` with `x * x`, this should speed up your method execution, since `pow` has general algorithm for double values

Comment: In your `checkRadius` method you can simply do `return distance < rad;`.   You may need to modify the inequality slightly to ensure `true` is returned when `distance == rad`   (e.g)  `return distance <= rad;`

Comment: You can certainly slightly improve performance by not using Math.pow but just (value * value), and precalculating the square of the radius. But that doesn't change the big-O complexity of the algorithm. This is O(n^2) on the number of turtles. But your overall "game loop" is probably already at least O(n^2) on the number of turtles, as they interact, and as long as the number of turtles has an upper bound, you can control how long the loop takes in practice.